# Jquery adding Id to header then removing it after a specific time

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I am trying to find the proper way to implement a jquery function on my webpage.  My goal is to add a animation id when my page is first visited then after 20 seconds I want to remove that specific animation id and add another id to take its place.  Here is my current code and webpage.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('header').attr('id', 'imageContainer');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would suggest you use a `class` for this as, to follow best practices, `id` attributes are not intended to be modified once created. To achieve the class removal you can use a timer, specifically, `setTimeout()`. Try this:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('header').addClass('imageContainer');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('header').removeClass('imageContainer');
    }, 20000); // 20 seconds
});
```

[**More information on setTimeout()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)